# Why the ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression Error?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

Can someone explain to me how I include all the selects in the group-by without getting an error?

The task I do is:"Show the manager's number and the smallest of his employees! Close all
Supervisors who do not have a supervisor. Close all
Groups whose minimum salary is less than 1000! Sort the output in descending order
Order of salaries" (Google Translate used)

```
select mgr as Vorgesetztennummer, min(sal) as Mitarbeiter
from emp 
where mgr is not null
group by mgr
having sal>1000
order by sal desc;
```

This a part of the emp table (just so you can see how it kind looks like):
[image]

Error:

```
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
```

Would be nice if someone can explain to me how and why the error happens in the first place.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an `GROUP BY attrs` clause in SQL then it is not possible to use attributes `a ⊄ attrs` in `SELECT`, `HAVING`, or `ORDER BY` outside of an aggregate function. In your example `sal ⊄ {mgr}`, therefore, your query probably should be

```
select mgr as Vorgesetztennummer, 
       min(sal) as Mitarbeiter
from emp 
where mgr is not null
group by mgr
having min(sal) > 1000
order by min(sal) desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select mgr as Vorgesetztennummer, min(sal) as Mitarbeiter
from emp 
where mgr is not null
group by mgr
having min(sal) >1000
order by 2 desc;
```